# Innovative Persistent Registry Entry Methods

Tags: windows, registry, persistence, malware, regedit

Prepping for a CEH certification test.  My question goes along these lines:

Situation: When attempting to add persistence to Windows malware, if the programmer chooses not to use one of the many existing RUN, AUTORUN, RUNONCE, etc. Windows registry entries ...

Question: Can he create an entirely new registry entry similar to \HKLM\SOFTWARE\My_Rootkit_Program\RUN and have it run automatically ... simply because it's named RUN?

Follow-On Question: Is the "magic" (repeatability) inherent in all registry entries named "RUN", *OR* does Windows use a concept similar to a PATH variable to locate and run those entries in registries named RUN (or similar)?

Follow-On Observation: If this latter hypothesis is correct, it follows that meddling with that registry PATH statement would be an advanced technique allowing programmers to build persistence into backwater places with names like \HKLM\SOFTWARE\CLASSES\7z\Updated_Compression_Routines.

Please forgive me (1) if this has been asked before and my searches didn't find the Q&A string (2) or I've misused specific terms.

Thanks ... Allen.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create your own runkey wherever you like. The valid runkeys are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Of course, you also have the service keys at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\...` which can be used to start drivers on boot. This can be used by rootkits, but generally malware will just use a normal runkey (or even place itself in the startup folder of the start menu).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Looking at the website, it does not cover AUTORUNS (and possibly other variations).  Is a fuller accounting of the RUNS, AUTORUNS, etc. registry PATH available?

Comment: I think you're getting your terminology a little confused. Those are the runkeys. The PATH variable and autoruns are different things entirely. If you want a good primer on how malware survives reboot, then have a look at http://www.evision.ws/itc/360download.php?filename=pdf/Malware_Startup_Locations.pdf

Comment: you're right; i'm unfamiliar with registry terminology, but i think i understand the basic concepts.  i know the PATH is used in DOS and Windows to find executables ... the term was used as an analogy to determine if it is/was possible to register new runkeys, then add those runkeys to the registry's hypothetical PATH variable.  if, the runkeys (of all sorts) are hard coded into an executable and therefore unchangable, then my theorized weakness is mitigated.

Comment: Yeah, the PATH tells the OS where executable files are stored. When you type ipconfig in a command prompt, the directories in the PATH variable will be searched for a executable file called ipconfig.exe. Malware does not _normally_ touch the PATH variable. But I think I see what you're getting at. You cannot register a new runkey, but you can change the ones that already exist.